# Where is codec_tag coming from in libavcodec's AVCodecContext?

Tags: ffmpeg, libav, libavcodec

In libavcodec 3.3.9, the structure AVCodecContext contains several fields, two of them being codec_tag and codec_id. I know codec_id's value comes from an enum and it is used to identify the codec.

I cannot find exactly how codec_tag is working without going through libavcodec source code. I have two different streams that have ac3 audio. One of them has codec_tag 0x06 and the other one 0x332d4341.

Running ffprobe for both streams yields the following information for the targeted audio channel:

For the one with tag 0x06

```
Stream #0:3[0x7d5](deu): Audio: ac3 ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 448 kb/s
```

For the other one:

```
Stream #0:3[0x8b2](dut): Audio: ac3 (AC-3 / 0x332D4341), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 384 kb/s
```

If I try to receive the second one into a file using ffmpeg and -codec copy, and then ffprobe the resulting file, I get:

```
Stream #0:1[0x101](dut): Audio: ac3 ([129][0][0][0] / 0x0081), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 384 kb/s
```

In all of this cases the codec_id field still remains the same one, AV_CODEC_ID_AC3.

My questions are:

- how is libavcodec determining codec_tag?
- why does it change when I receive the stream copying the codecs?

Comment: Have you looked in [`utils.c` of `libavformat`](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavformat/utils.c)?

Comment: My guess to your second question is that `libavformat` is using the `codec_tag` provided by the `libavcodec`, and some codec has multiple tags associated with it. `-acodec copy` passes the encoded stream as is but the muxer gets the codec info from the detected codec.

Comment: [One more link](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/search?p=2&q=AV_CODEC_ID_AC3) to indulge your curiosity. The tag is definitely format dependent. you can see many formats are setting its own tag(s) for AC3.